# How to avoid app crash when using Async-task in Fragments?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show images in grid-view using tab-swipe. But when include async-task to fetch images from json URL the app does not even starting. It just crashes and closed. Here is my code.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {
public GamesFragment(){}

// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
GridView gridview;
GridViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items;
private Button button;
static String CATEGORY = "category";
int setlimit = 6;
int tolimit = 5;

static String IMAGE = "image";




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_main, container, false);

   new DownloadJSON().execute();
    return rootView;
}
// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Student Government App");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL
                        ("http://jsonurl.com");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("wallpaper");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects

                map.put("category", jsonobject.getString("category"));

                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        gridview = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridViewCustom);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

}
```

How can i prevent it from app crash? Any help would be be great.

```
Logcat:

    07-03 15:22:36.692      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-    AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41353570 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41352cb0  {info.androidhive.tabsswipe/info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity}}
07-03 15:22:36.707      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@41352cb0
07-03 15:22:36.904      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-03 15:22:36.944      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-03 15:22:36.989      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-03 15:22:37.003      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe E/WindowManager﹕ Activity info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4136f300 that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4136f300 that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:294)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:151)
            at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
            at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.GamesFragment$DownloadJSON.onPreExecute(GamesFragment.java:65)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.GamesFragment.onCreateView(GamesFragment.java:48)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2161)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2131)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1242)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1435)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1127)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 15:22:37.004      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-03 15:22:37.004      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@41352cb0
07-03 15:22:37.004      838-838/info.androidhive.tabsswipe D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

Comment: Post your logcat's stack trace. Let us see why your application crashes first.

Comment: You did not post enough of your logcat as the real crash info lacks. Please post more. And for an advise how to make the code better: put `jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL()`in a try/catch block. And `return null;` in a catch block as otherwise it will go on executing code which is not what you want. Put more Log.d() statements in doInBackground so you can see how far your code gets executed before it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You should move `gridview` initialized  in your `onCreateView(...)` before  `new DownloadJSON().execute();`

```
 gridview = (GridView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.gridViewCustom);
```

Comment: Tried. But Still its crashing.

Comment: @user3652550 make sure you've `GridView` with id `gridViewCustom` in your `gridview_main` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Change you oncreateview like this

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_main, container, false);
           gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewCustom);
       new DownloadJSON().execute();
        return rootView;
    }

private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
                   ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading , Please wait...");
                        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        progressDialog.show();

                        super.onPreExecute();
                    }
```

change your onPostExecute this way

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
         mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        gridview = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridViewCustom);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

       super.onPostExecute(arg);
    }
```

}

Comment: the error is leaked window, try changing the progress dialog like above and cancel the progress dialog inside onPostExecute..

Comment: r u  sure you are getting the same window leaked error...try cancelling the progress dialod before setting the adapter dunno the correct problen but try

Comment: in your onPostExecute where is 
super.onPostExecute(arg); add that too... ands try

Comment: Mmmm... i would say: remove all super calls.

Answer (score -1):

You open That app in Debugging mode
and see the error in console (choose warning) and find the error and clear it